# Elasticsearch nodejs client timeout for exists and existsAlias

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm getting timeout errors when trying to use the elasticsearch nodejs client to check if an index or an alias exists on the cluster.

The elastic instance is running on docker with this docker-compose file, it responds on the browser and to a client.ping() call:

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
      - cluster.name=es-cluster
      - node.name=es1
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    expose:
      - "9200"
      - "9300"
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    networks:
      - docker-network

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local

networks:
  docker-network:
```

This is the class that connects to the cluster:

```
export default class EsClient {

    private static client: Client;

    public static getClient() {
        if (!EsClient.client) {
            const host = `http://localhost:9200`;
            EsClient.client = new Client({
                node: host,
                maxRetries: 5,
                requestTimeout: 10000,
                resurrectStrategy: 'ping'
            });
        }
        return EsClient.client;
    }

}
```

This is how I check if an alias exists:

```
    static async aliasExists(alias: string) {
        const client = EsClient.getClient();
        const params: any = { name: alias };
        const result = await client.indices.existsAlias(params); // This times out
        // Do stuff
    }
```

The timeout error:

```
TimeoutError: Request timed out
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\projects\node-cdn\node_modules\@elastic\elasticsearch\lib\Connection.js:89:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at Socket.emitRequestTimeout (_http_client.js:690:9)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:469:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {
  name: 'TimeoutError',
  meta: {
    body: null,
    statusCode: null,
    headers: null,
    warnings: null,
    meta: {
      context: null,
      request: [Object],
      name: 'elasticsearch-js',
      connection: [Object],
      attempts: 5,
      aborted: false
    }
  }
}
```

This is the response from a client.ping() using the same class to obtain the client object:

```
{
  body: true,
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'content-length': '510'
  },
  warnings: null,
  meta: {
    context: null,
    request: { params: [Object], options: [Object], id: 1 },
    name: 'elasticsearch-js',
    connection: {
      url: 'http://localhost:9200/',
      id: 'http://localhost:9200/',
      headers: {},
      deadCount: 0,
      resurrectTimeout: 0,
      _openRequests: 0,
      status: 'alive',
      roles: [Object]
    },
    attempts: 0,
    aborted: false
  }
}
```